# Why it is blinking only one time?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to achieve similar functionality as shown in below fiddle to my table

http://jsfiddle.net/anuradha/w9UQn/

I have tried similarly as shown in this code

```
setInterval(findYellow,1000);     
 function findYellow(){ 

  $("td.greenclass").each(function(){ 
       $(this).toggleClass("greenclass");
     })
    }
```

But it is only blinking for one time initially .

https://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/3343/

Comment: You're removing the class from an element, then trying to find the same element later with that class that no longer exists on it... :)

Answer (score 6):

Does the `.greenclass` element exist once you remove its class `greenclass`? (rhetorical question)

To fix it, assign the element collection to a variable outside the interval callback.

https://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/3345/

Comment: @OP Instead of polluting the global scope, you can use https://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/3344/

Comment: No problem, @PreethiJain, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy and now you're polluting the class scope (doesn't exist, but in this case has the same performance effects)...

Comment: @shomz too fast for me, nice answer

Comment: hmm. I don't want to get into any unproductive arguments here. I stick with my point though. No offense.

Comment: Sure, I understand, I just wanted to say it's not that relevant in this case... You can put everything in a closure, which is even better.